# Batch script to iterate through directories starting with a specific string

Tags: loops, for-loop, batch-file, move

I'm currently having to manually edit the batch file to manually tell it which directory to work on.

The directories it has to crawl will ALWAYS start with "2020-" (at least for this year), and sometimes there will be multiple of them if I miss a day.

(if it's any easier, they will ALWAYS be in this format: "0000-00-00")

Is there a way to edit this to account for that?

I've tried just making the source_directory just "2020*" but I know that's probably not how this works lol, any help or pointer in the right direction would be amazing.

```
@echo off

pushd %~dp0

SET source_directory=2020-05-03
SET target_directory=%~dp0

for /f %%a IN ('dir "%source_directory%" /b') do (
move %source_directory%\%%a %target_directory%
)
```

Comment: If 2020 is the prefix you are looking for, then `2020-??-??` should do it, unless you have directories for the form 2020-aa-aa where `a` is alpha characters.  If you do, you can always check the result in %%a for any non-numeric values and skip performing the move.

Comment: Does this script get run each day for the date specified in source_directory?

Comment: I would like it to be ran automatically, so I'll go through task scheduler. But currently I've had to do it manually because of the limitation, so sometimes it would be put off, and then multiple days would stack up. so I'd have "2020-01-01" and, "2020-01-02", etc. I would have it just use the current date as the variable, but it doesn't account for that.

Comment: Thank you for the info regarding '??', I've incorporated it into my solution.

Comment: `for /F %%S in ('dir /B /A:D "????-??-??" ^| findstr /X "[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]"') do ( ... )` sould only allow numerals in place of `?`. But still I don't understand what you're trying to achieve; at the moment you're iterating through all matching sub-directories and moving files from there, but is that really what you want, or do you rather want to move files from the sub-directory with today's date?

Comment: And please remove your solution from the question and post it as an answer instead, because that's exactly what answers are for...

Comment: I have removed your latest edit @dxrth, please add it as an answer if you've chosen it as your solution.

Comment: My bad. Also, sorry for not explaining enough. My goal is to move all files out of any sub directory that is named with a date, and bring the files up a folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I don't use SO too often so I forget how things need to be done.

This is the solution I've come up with. I don't think it's the intuitive way of doing this, but I don't understand batch well enough to do this without nesting loops.

```
@echo off

pushd %~dp0

SET source_directory=????-??-??
SET target_directory=%~dp0

for /d %%s in (%source_directory%) do (
    for /f %%a IN ('dir "%%s" /b') do (
        move %%s\%%a %target_directory%
    )
)
```